# Npm install issue HOMEBREW

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew

This is the error I got:

```
npm install error 3097 error command sh -c node scripts/build.js 3098 error Building: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/16.5.0/bin/node
```

I just switched to Mac from Windows and cloned my repo. Tried to run npm install to install the packages for my react app and got this error.

I installed node with homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seemed to be related with installing node with home brew. As a quick and easy fix I just ran `brew uninstall node` and then went to the nodejs website and installed it for mac manually. This took care of the issues and I was able to install my packages successfully.